# How to get zoom meeting details report with zoom API?

Tags: api, zoom-sdk

I am trying to get zoom meeting details report using API. The report should be same as "Active Hosts - Report Type "Meeting List with Details"- which I can get from UI.The sample report is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rDxBuWk9lObZPmmgKrELrQHN5pcqq1L3LiNvg0SZ6kk/edit?usp=sharing

But instead of getting the report from UI manually, I want to get the report  using ZOOM API with python script which should run as a job periodically.
SO my query is:
1)how can I get the same report using zoom API?
2) Should I call multiple API? if yes, which are APIs should I call to get the report?

Any kinds of help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

*************** 2nd Part *******

I have explored a little after this post. I have tried this API endpoint. What I ended up is below:

Please check this document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rDxBuWk9lObZPmmgKrELrQHN5pcqq1L3LiNvg0SZ6kk/edit#gid=1137066976

Here I specified all the fields those I need to extract to get the target report which is named as UI report in the spreed sheet. To get this report I tried to call 3 APIs:

1. Get List meeting: https://api.zoom.us/v2/metrics/meetings
2. Get Active/Inactive host reports: "https://api.zoom.us/v2/report/users
3. Get Meeting Participants: [https://api.zoom.us/report/meetings/{meetingId}/participants](https://api.zoom.us/report/meetings/%7BmeetingId%7D/participants)

To my understanding I thought to get all the field of UI report I need to call these 3 APIs. The first 2 API calls are working fine. But when I am in the 3rd call which is “Meeting participants” where I need to provide “meetingid” as a path key. Here in my educational institute (University) we have thousands of meetingid , for example for a single day I found there are 28,800 numbers of unique meeting ids. It might be more than 30,000 if I try with larger date range(for 7 days or 30 days). In this case the Meeting participants call will take each meetingid and execute the API call which will exceed the date limit. How to resolve this issue?
Is there any other better way or any straightforward API out there which can give me the almost the same report as the Target UI report? Please help.
Thank you.